# Can I swap keys in Unity's Input system if there are duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implent function which is Rebind Keys with Unity's Input System and if there is a any duplicate keys, swap two keys.
I found the way how to detect if there is a duplicate keys, but I can't figure out how to change keys.
Could anyone give me some advices?
This is my code.

```
void RebindStart(InputAction rebindKey, int bindingIndex, string excludeDevice1, string excludeDevice2, string excludeDevice3)
    {
        isBusy = true;
        rebindKey.Disable();
        rebindingOperation = rebindKey.PerformInteractiveRebinding().WithTargetBinding(bindingIndex)
            .WithControlsExcluding(excludeDevice1)
            .WithControlsExcluding(excludeDevice2)
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/capsLock")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/leftMeta")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/contextMenu")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/numlock")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/printScreen")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/scrollLock")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<Keyboard>/pause")
            .WithControlsExcluding("<keyboard>/anyKey")
            .WithCancelingThrough("*/{Cancel}")
            .OnCancel(opeation => RebindCancel(rebindKey))
            .OnComplete(operation => RebindEnd(rebindKey, bindingIndex, excludeDevice1, excludeDevice2, excludeDevice3))
            .Start();
    }
    void RebindEnd(InputAction action, int bindingIndex, string excludeDevice1, string excludeDevice2, string excludeDevice3)
    {
        if (isDuplicate(action, bindingIndex))
        {
            rebindingOperation.Dispose();
            action.RemoveBindingOverride(bindingIndex);
            RebindStart(action, bindingIndex, excludeDevice1, excludeDevice2, excludeDevice3);
        }

        itemBoard.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        itemBoard.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        action.Enable();
        Debug.Log(action.ToString() + " : " +  action.GetBindingDisplayString(bindingIndex));
        
        rebindingOperation.Dispose();
        isBusy = false;
        allCompositeParts = false;
    }
    void RebindCancel(InputAction action)
    {
        action.Enable();
        rebindingOperation.Dispose();
        
        isBusy = false;
        allCompositeParts = false;
    }


public bool isDuplicate(InputAction action, int bindingIndex)
    {
        InputBinding newInputBinding = action.bindings[bindingIndex];
        InputBinding tempBinding = new InputBinding();
        
        
        
        foreach (InputBinding binding in action.actionMap.bindings)
        {
            if (binding.action == newInputBinding.action)
                continue;
            if (binding.effectivePath == newInputBinding.effectivePath)
            {
                tempBinding = binding;
                
                Debug.Log("Duplicate Key Exist :" + newInputBinding.effectivePath);
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        if (action.bindings[bindingIndex].isComposite)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < bindingIndex; i++)
            {
                if (action.bindings[i].effectivePath == newInputBinding.effectivePath)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Duplicate Key Exist : " + newInputBinding.effectivePath);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } 
        return false;
    }
```

I tried to invert InputBinding to InputAction, but I didn't made it.
If i thought wrong is there any way to invert?

Comment: in the case of a duplicate you seem to not swap anything ... you just initiate a new `RebindStart` process for the same action ... I would probably rather let `isDuplicate` also "return" (`out` parameter) the other action that is the duplicate